# Trigonometrical limit $\lim\limits_{ x\to 0 } \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^3}?$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Can you help me solve this without using de l'Hôpital's rule (just using Standard rules):

$$ \lim_{ x\to 0 } \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^3}? $$

Comment: Solve for what? I assume for $x\rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: So many edits...........This going to become a Wiki post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting $y = x^3$, note that your limit is the same as
$$
  \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(y^{1 \over 3}) - y^{1 \over 3}\cos(y^{1 \over 3})}{y}
$$
If you let the mean value theorem be one of your standard rules, then you can say that ${\displaystyle \frac{\sin(y^{1 \over 3}) - y^{1 \over 3}\cos(y^{1 \over 3})}{y} = f'(z)}$ for some $z$ between $0$ and $y$. Calculating the derivative reveals that
$$
  f'(z) = {1 \over 3}{\sin(z^{1 \over 3}) \over z^{1 \over 3}}
$$
Observe that as $y$ goes to zero, so does $z$, and therefore so does $z^{1 \over 3}$. Using that ${\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {\sin(x) \over x} = 1}$ one sees therefore that
$$
  \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f'(z) = {1 \over 3}
$$
So ${1 \over 3}$ is the limit.

Comment: That is exactly L'hopital after the first substitution. and how do you prove $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$ without power series and without L'hopital ?

Comment: L'hopital requires a more general version of the mean value theorem than this. As for the limit, it is done in many Calc I textbooks using just geometry. No power series or L'Hopital is needed.

Comment: You need cauchy mean value theorem vor L'hopitale taking the function $$h(x)= f(x) (g(b)-g(a)) -g(x) (f(b)-f(a))$$ implies the more general version. You avoid the more general version by the first substitution where you didn't prove you can do it.

Comment: So I avoided the more general version of the mean value theorem, and avoided L'hopital's rule. This is what the asker wanted.

Comment: you used a substitution in the limit which is way more non trivial than power series at all. The asker wanted No L'hopital and in fact you proved the easy L'hopital I persoanlly think that this is totally silly.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis The substitution just requires that as $x$ goes to zero, so does $x^3$. This is just the fact that $y = x^3$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Not exactly advanced stuff. And I didn't use L'hopital, I used an easier version of the mean value theorem than a version used in the proof of L'hopital. This is not the same as using L'hopital. At any rate, I am done discussing this with you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8193/discussion-between-dominic-michaelis-and-zarrax)

Answer (score 4):

Use that 
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}\mp \cdots$$
and that 
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\pm\dots$$
Hence
$$\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}=\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}- x+\frac{x^3}{2}- \frac
{x^5}{4!} \pm \dots}{x^3}=\frac{1}{3} +\frac{x^2}{5!}-\frac{x^2}{4!}\pm \dots$$
Hence the Limit of
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{3} +\frac{x^2}{5!}-\frac{x^2}{4!}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: If he can't use L'Hopital's do you expect expansions to be OK?

Comment: yeah i epect them to be ok, the power series are way more elementary than L'hopital

Comment: But power series involve differentiation. And so does l'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: @pen nope they don't we defined the $\exp$ function over $$\exp(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$ and $\sin$ and $cos$ over $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\cdot (\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix))$ there you don't need any differention to get the power series

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Hmm, I think l'Hospital is much more fundamental, so I cannot expect myself to know that before l'Hospital...

Comment: @pen to get the power series of sin and cos you don'T actually need to know that they are differenctiabe with the definitions we have made

Comment: What if you follow the circle definition of sine and cos?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee thats the same with eulers formula

Comment: To show a power series actual equals the original function requires bounds on the error term of the power series. This is not particularly elementary.

Comment: @Zarrax not if the actual function IS a power series. I only need elementar division.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ are not normally defined in terms of power series in a a calculus class, which is probably where the question came from. They are defined using the geometry of circles as in every precalculus class.

Comment: @Zarrax Depends, some professors on my faculty define $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ like power series, on first year of faculty.

Comment: @Cortizol That is rare (at least in my country)

Comment: @Zarrax in my country it is always introduced in the way i told, and i guess that is the most usefull one

Comment: @Zarrax I just know that some professors use that definition. I didn't learn that way. My professor prove that exist unit function $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $h(x+y)=h(x)h(y)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{h(x)-1}{x}=i$ and then define $\cos x = \Re (h(x))$ and $\sin x = \Im (h(x))$. Sorry for spam.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I like the approach of Dominic Michaelis, here is another one using infinite products.

First note that
\begin{align}
\sin(x) &= x \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}) \\
&= x(1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} + O(x^4))
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\cos(x) &=  \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2(n-1/2)^2})
\\
\Leftrightarrow  x\cos(x) &=  x\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2(n-1/2)^2})
\\ &= x(1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 (n-1/2)^2} + O(x^4))
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}&= \frac{1}{x^2}\Bigl[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 (n-1/2)^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2} +O(x^4) \Bigr]
\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^2 (n-1/2)^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^2 n^2} +O(x^2)  \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2} \Bigl[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ (n-1/2)^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \Bigr]+O(x^2)
\end{align}
Together with the fact that 
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ (n-1/2)^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{2} \quad \text{and} \\
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{align}
we get 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{x^3}
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2} \Bigl[\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ (n-1/2)^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \Bigr]+O(x^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{\pi^2} (\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}) +O(x^2)
\\ &= \frac{1}{3} + O(x^2) = 0 \quad \text{for } x\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
Note: I am aware, that this is not as simple as requested by Maths'problem and even more complex than the answer of Dominic Michaelis. We also need to know the infinite products and the identities involving $\sum 1/n^2$ and $\sum 1/(n-1/2)^2$. However, I just wanted to provide another method to solve the problem.

Comment: why minus? (+1) of course